# Unable to mkdir for log file after packaging electron app

Tags: typescript, npm, electron

When running my electron app after running `electron-forge package` on my mac, I get the following exception after start up when trying to create the logger:

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'log'
    at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:987:3)
    at File._createLogDirIfNotExist
```

I do not see this error when running in dev mode with the renderer and main running separately.  I thought it might be file permissions at first, but I don't see anything obvious.

Comment: Hello @michael - were you able to resolve this? I'm facing the exact same issue

Comment: No, i was not.  We ended up abandoning the electron app.